# Search inside a string

Tags: php, string, search

```
$variable = 'of course it is unnecessary [http://google.com], 
but it is simple["very simple"], and this simple question clearly
needs a simple, understandable answer [(where is it?)] in plain English'
```

Value of this variable everytime changes.

What I trying to do is to get the text from `[...]`. So, if there is `[(google)]`, the match should be `(google)`.

I'm searching for a solution, which can do each of these actions:

1. get all matches of [...], write into `$all`
2. get only the *first* match, write into `$first`
3. get only the *last* match, write into `$last`
4. remove all matches of [...] from the variable (erase)
5. remove only first match
6. remove only last match

Tried different regex for this, like `/[\(.*?\)]/`, but the results aren't what one might expect.

Comment: @jcubic, what is the difference?

Comment: bracket are special regex characters, if you want to match brackets you must escape it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$variable = 'of course it is unnecessary [http://google.com], 
but it is simple["very simple"], and this simple question clearly
needs a simple, understandable answer [(where is it?)] in plain English';

preg_match_all("/(\[(.*?)\])/", $variable, $matches);

$first = reset($matches[2]);
$last = end($matches[2]);
$all = $matches[2];

# To remove all matches
foreach($matches[1] as $key => $value) {
    $variable = str_replace($value, '', $variable);
}

# To remove first match
$variable = str_replace($first, '', $variable);

# To remove last match
$variable = str_replace($last, '', $variable);
```

Note that if you use str_replace to replace the tags, all similar occurences of the tags will be removed if such exist, not just the first.

Comment: there should be a way to remove all, first or only the last match

Comment: **$first** is **[(where is it?)]** it should be a **(where is it?)** (remove [ and ])