# Filter only shortcode from a post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a contact page plugin for my blog.The shortcode using for this is 
`[my-shortcode]`.
Is there anyways to filter only the shortcode from the content.
Eg: 
`Test post [my-shortcode] Demo widget`.here i need to filter only the shortcode.Thank you

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question, asked barely a couple of hours ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734519/seach-inside-a-string which also extracts information from between [ and ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to get the value of brackets within a string like so.

```
if(preg_match_all('/\[(.*?)\]/',$_POST['my_key'],$matches))
{
    foreach($matches as $match)
    {
        if($match[1] == 'my-short-code')
        {
            //Do whetever
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: `match[1]` may be `match[0]`